# Saving Arrays Between Classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Currently attempting to save an array that is populated according to which cells in a UITableView are chosen and saving this array in an instance of a seperate object. I am getting the array to populate just fine, however, my save method, which is an IBAction that is invoked  by clicking on a Bar Button doesn't seem to be working. Here is some code:

```
-(IBAction)saveWorkout:(id)sender {
    Workouts *new = [[Workouts alloc] init];
    [new addNewWorkout:customWorkout];

    [customWorkout removeAllObjects];
}
```

This code is from the first class.

And here is the code for my addNewWorkouts method in the Workouts class:

```
-(void)addNewWorkout:(NSMutableArray*)array {
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    temp = array;

    self.workoutList = temp;

    [temp release];

}
```

Here is my "Workout.h"

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Workouts : NSObject {
    NSString *workoutName;
    NSMutableArray *workoutList;
    NSString *description;
    int *reps;
    int *weights;
    int *sets;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *workoutName;
@property (nonatomic, retain ) NSString *description;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *workoutList;

-(void)addNewWorkout:(NSMutableArray*)array;
```

@end

Before running this code, I get a Warning from Xcode saying that 'Workouts may not respond to 'addNewWorkouts.'

Anyone know what is causing this error? Once I build & run, I click on the Save button and the app crashes with a unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b04410 error.

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but once you get past this error, your code will still not work right. I'd suggest checking out the memory management rules: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1 (Hint: That `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` at the top is a leak, the `[temp release]` at the bottom is an overrelease, and `self.workoutList = temp` may or may not work right depending on how the setter for the `workoutList` property is implemented)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `[new addNewWorkouts:customWorkout]`
when the method's selector is `addNewWorkout:` (note that there is no plural in the method name)

This will make a bad method call and result in a crash.

Also, there is a problem with the memory management of the addNewWorkout method.

```
1- NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
2- temp = array;
3- self.workoutList = temp;
4- [temp release];
```

You allocate a new NSMutableArray on line 1, then lose its reference on line 2 when you replace its pointer by 'array'. The allocation you just made is lost and the program will leak.

Then, on line 4, you send a release message to 'temp' which actually points to 'array', resulting in the release of the parameter that you received and not the temporary object.

Is there a reason whny you create a temporary array? You can just assign the property and make the property copy or retain it, depending on your needs.

Comment: The code still won't work right because the memory management is wrong, but this will indeed fix the specific error in question.

Comment: Console also reveals this error: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b04410

Comment: Yes I edited my answer to clarify that. At first I was more answering on the crash / warning issue.

Comment: In addition to the errors J_D points out: Unless the setter for `workoutList` copies the array, you're deleting all the objects in the array as soon as you leave the method. This is probably a mistake.

Comment: Depending on how you declared the property 'workoutList' and how you reuse customWorkout.  Try @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray * workoutList;

Comment: Added my "Workout.h" for referencing.

Comment: With your current .h, workoutList is declared as a retained property, meaning that indeed as long as your object is referencing it, it will not be deallocated (assuming that memory management is correct), but it also means that any modification to the original array (customWorkout in your case) will impact the one in self.workoutList.